# ¿Como convertir varchar a datetime en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Buen día a todos, quiero convertir este dato `14 de Febrero 1986` en `sql` a `datetime`, pero el `convert`

```
CONVERT(datetime,fecha_nacimiento)
```

No lo convierte.
¿Hay alguna manera de convertirlo?

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo sería: 1. Estableciendo el lenguaje a español con: **`SET LANGUAGE Spanish;`**  y 2. Quitando la palabra `de` de la fecha que estás recibiendo, y aplicando `CAST` a dicha cadena ya limpia: **`SELECT CAST(REPLACE('14 de Febrero 1986',' de ',' ') AS DATETIME) fecha;`**

Comment: @A.Cedano tu comentario es una buena respuesta!, ¿por que no lo agregas como tal?. Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de una forma simple del siguiente modo:

1. Estableciendo el lenguaje a español con: [`SET LANGUAGE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

   ```
   SET LANGUAGE Spanish;
   ```
2. Quitando mediante [`REPLACE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) la palabra `de` de la fecha que estás recibiendo, pues esta palabra impide que la cadena sea reconocida como una fecha válida.  Luego, aplicas [`CAST`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) a dicha cadena ya validada. Por ejemplo:

   ```
   SELECT CAST(REPLACE('14 de Febrero 1986',' de ',' ') AS DATETIME) fecha;
   ```

   **Resultado:**

   ```
   fecha
   14.02.1986 00:00:00
   ```

### Solución óptima para SQL Server 2012+

Si estás trabajando con SQL Server 2012+ puedes implementar [`TRY_CAST`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), la cual te dará un valor `NULL` en los datos erróneos. Puede ser un recurso interesante a la hora de *normalizar* los valores, pasándolos a una columna del tipo `DATETIME`, que sería lo más correcto. Pues al contar todavía con los datos de la columna actualmente declarada como `VARCHAR`, podrás ordenar alfabéticamente por la nueva columna producida por `TRY_CAST`, corregir los valores errónes, aplicar de nuevo la consulta y tener de una forma simple los datos normalizados y sin riesgo de error.

La consulta con `TRY_CAST` sería idéntica a la consulta mencionada en el punto 2.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(REPLACE('14 de Febrero 1986',' de ',' ') AS DATETIME) fecha;
```

**Resultado:**

```
fecha
14.02.1986 00:00:00
```

Veamos el resultado sobre un hipotético valor erróneo:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(REPLACE('14 de Febrer 1986',' de ',' ') AS DATETIME) fecha;
```

**Resultado:**

```
fecha
NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

El problema que tienes, es que la cadena tiene un formato que no parece coincidir con algunas de las opciones de conversión de fechas de [`CAST` o `CONVERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Lo que puede hacer es trabajar un poco la cadena para llevarla a un formato más compatible. Por ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(100)
SELECT  @Cadena = '14 de Febrero 1986'

DECLARE @Meses TABLE  (
    nombre VARCHAR(15),
    numero VARCHAR(2)
)

INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Enero','01')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Febrero','02')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Marzo','03')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Abril','04')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Mayo','05')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Junio','06')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Julio','07')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Agosto','08')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Septiembre','09')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Setiembre','09')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Octubre','10')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Noviembre','11')
INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Diciembre','12')

SELECT  @Cadena = REPLACE(@Cadena, 'de ', '')
SELECT  @Cadena = REPLACE(@Cadena,nombre,numero)
    FROM @Meses

SELECT  @Cadena = REPLACE(@Cadena, ' ', '-')
SELECT  @Cadena = RIGHT('0'+SUBSTRING(@Cadena, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @Cadena)-1),2) + SUBSTRING(@Cadena, CHARINDEX('-', @Cadena) , LEN(@Cadena))

-- Resultado final
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, @Cadena, 105)
```

Básicamente a) quitamos el texto `de`, b) reemplazamos los nombres de los meses por su representación numérica, c) agregamos los guiones para separar cada parte de la fecha y d) convertimos a `datetime` usando el formato `105`.

Otra posibilidad, mucho mejor pero solo si tuvieras una versión de SQL Server 2012 o superior, es usar [`PARSE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @Cadena VARCHAR(100)
SELECT  @Cadena = '14 de Febrero 1986'

SELECT PARSE(@Cadena AS datetime USING 'es-ES') AS Result
```

Comment: Como observación solo debería dejar la linea: `INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Septiembre','09')` , esta otra: 
`INSERT INTO @Meses (nombre, numero) VALUES ('Setiembre','09')` está demás.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez, fue adrede, Septiembre es un mes que se puede ver escrito de las dos formas, y en sí el reemplazo de más es inocuo. De todas formas está bien la aclaración que haces, así el OP puede quitar la versión que con seguridad sabe que no va a usar.

Comment: Edité mi respuesta por que ciertamente la conversión de la primera opción podía llegar a fallar para los días 1 al 9 si estos no vienen con 0 a la izquierda.

Answer (score 0):

Otro método:

```
declare @Fechas table (Fecha varchar(30) )
insert into @Fechas
values 
        ('14 de Enero 1986'),
        ('1 de Febrero 1986'),
        ('3 de Marzo 1986'),
        ('23 de Abril 1986'),
        ('6 de Mayo 1986'),
        ('11 de Junio 1986'),
        ('30 de Julio 1986'),
        ('19 de Agosto 1986'),
        ('24 de Septiembre 1986'),
        ('16 de Octubre 1986'),
        ('27 de Noviembre 1986'),
        ('15 de Diciembre 1986')

select  reverse(substring(reverse(Fecha), 1, 4)) + '-' +
        case
            when Fecha like '%ENE%' then '1'
            when Fecha like '%FEB%' then '2'
            when Fecha like '%MARZ%' then '3'
            when Fecha like '%ABR%' then '4'
            when Fecha like '%MAY%' then '5'
            when Fecha like '%JUN%' then '6'
            when Fecha like '%JUL%' then '7'
            when Fecha like '%AGOS%' then '8'
            when Fecha like '%SEPT%' then '9'
            when Fecha like '%OCT%' then '10'
            when Fecha like '%NOV%' then '11'
            when Fecha like '%DIC%' then '12'
        end
        + '-' + substring(Fecha, 1,  charindex(' ', Fecha)) 
from @Fechas
```